# Router.back() won't work in incognito mode or when link comes from different source

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router, next-router

i am using Nextjs as react framework for my ecommerce website. My product detail page have an custom back button which is having **Router.back()** function. This works normal when browsing back and forth in website. But whenever i copy the product detail link and open directly in incognito mode the custom back button won't work...!!

Anyone have solution for this ?

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue, can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: it's resolved now ... thanks anyways :)

Comment: @Gurupalsingh Could you share how you resolved it, just in case someone faces the same issue.